# How to get extended attributes to New-ADuser cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a new AD user through a script. Unfortunately there are several unusual attributes of the account I need to set. I tried to use the `-OtherAttributes` parameter, but it didn't work, Powershell said they are unknown parameters. I'm talking about these attributes:
[image: Extended attributes to set in AD user]

Anyone knows how to set these parameters?

Comment: `-OtherAttributes` is the way to go. Please share the code you used + the exact error message

Comment: Just found out I made the most stupid mistake ever - a typo. I put everywhere the name "extension Attribute#" instead of "extensionAttribute#"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with Set-AdUser?

```
Set-ADUser $Name –replace @{extensionAttribute5="Company"}
```

or with a hash table

```
$Attributes = @{
   Name = "Test User"
   SamAccountName = "Testuser"
   Enabled = $true
   Path = "OU=Users,DC=Domain,DC=local"
   AccountPassword = "1234567"
   ChangePasswordAtLogon = $False
   GivenName = "Test"
   EmployeeID = "1234"
   Surname = "Test User"
   DisplayName = "Test User"
   Initials = "TU"
   Description = "Test User for tests"
   UserPrincipalName = "Test@domain.local"
   Office = "Test Office"
   Company = "Test Company"
   Department = "Test Department"
   Division = "Test Division"
   EmailAddress = "test@test.local"
       OtherAttributes = @{ 
           extensionAttribute4 = "Test Data"
           extensionAttribute5 = "Test Data"
       }
   }

New-ADUser @Attributes -PassThru
```